# How to remove the Bubble Notification of Empathy from the Notification Area

Tags: 11.10, empathy, notification-area

There is a Bubble notification that appears in the notification area apart from the Mail Icon Message. I only want one notification icon telling me when a new message has arrived.

Right now as seen in the image:

[image]

I have the MAIL Icon (Which is White right now but turns blue when a new message arrives) and the First green icon, which is the bubbling talk icon that I want to remove.

When a message appears both of them tell me a new message has arrives. I only want the MAIL icon (The white one between the Keyboard and the Bluetooth Icon)

Comment: is this Unity or gnome-classic? Are you using the notification-applet as well as the indicator-applet?

Comment: This is old. It was fixed alone so I am guessing a bug fix appeared for 11.10 for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by upgrading the system. It does not appear in all PC. For example in a HP DV6000 I tested did not appear but it did on a Intel Desktop PC.